# How to remove mutilple alert box calling bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem that if i add email input dynamically than after validation i get to many alert if i entered some value in first input and than in secound email field

```
function isEmail(email) {

emailValue=email.value;

var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;

var res = regex.test(emailValue);

if (res==false){

alert("Enter valid email");

  }
}
```

Code to create email field dynamically-

```
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("email"));
        var input_e = document.createElement("input");
        input_e.type = "email";
        input_e.id= id+'_email';
        input_e.name= "email[]";
        input_e.required =true;
        input_e.setAttribute('onblur', 'return isEmail(email)');
        container.appendChild(input_e);

        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

HTML code:

```
      Email :
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Enter email" onblur="return isEmail(email)" required>
        <input type="button" id="newAutocomplete" onclick="addFields();" value="add" />
      <br><br>
 <div id="container" />
```

Comment: how many alert you see? is it fixed or varies always?

Comment: Just check if each appended input has a unique `id`

Comment: its goes in loop and showing unlimited alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you property, you must use-

```
function isEmail(email) {

  emailValue=email.value;

var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;

  var res = regex.test(emailValue);

  if (res==false && !window.alertedOnce){
  window.alertedOnce = true; // Use like a flag and set-rest as per your requirement
  alert("Enter valid email");

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ishank dubey